# Optimization of the following block of code

Tags: c, performance, optimization

*Consider the following piece of C code. Describe three different optimizations (including their name) that may improve the performance, why they improve the performance, and how the code looks after the optimizations. Assume that all variables are declared and initiated/have some value before the code sequence.*

```
 condition2 = condition1 | input_flag; 

 for(i=0;i<10000;i++){

   if ( (t1==0) && (t2==0) && (t3==0) ) 
      a = sin(45∗b∗3.14/180);  

   else  
      a = sin(135∗b∗3.14/180);  

   if ( condition2 & COND1 ) 
      DoOneThing(a);

   else if ( condition2 & COND2 ) 
      DoAnotherThing(a); 

   else 
      DoYetAnotherThing(a); 
 }
```

I have the following example of code in C. I am learning the methods of performance optimization, but I am quite new to it and don't know to optimize the following code...

Perhaps one way would be to initialize `a` inside a loop. But I can't think of any other method to optimize it.

Comment: Hint: does `a` depend on `i` ?

Comment: A possible "optimization" would be to use boolean operators instead of bitwise ones. Otherwise no short circuiting can happen.

Comment: Indentation is almost correct now.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No it doesn't. This means that I can take the first if statement outside of the loop right?

Comment: There use to be times where `++i` was considered faster than `i++`.

Comment: Would perhaps transforming "for" loop into another loop type be better?

Comment: In fact none of all those conditions depend on the counter. So the decisions to be taken only need to be taken once, typically outside the loop.

Comment: @jakamojster _This means that I can take the first if statement outside of the loop right_ : yes that's where you can optimize most, but that's not all.

Comment: Regarding the last `if` statement if we create `if` that is checking the `condition2` and than in the sub `if` checking `COND1`and `COND2`, would that be faster?

Comment: The first paragraph makes it sound like homework, and bad homework at that. This is terrible code, even if it's optimized.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey It's not a homework, it is a example of a question we can get on exam. I didn't find any related information in lectures so I turned to all of you for help.

Comment: @jakamojster: Well, in the first place, nothing obviously depends on *i*, so why the loop? Is *b* an integer? *3.14/180* is *approximately* the conversion factor from degrees to radians. If *b* is an integer, why bother calling *sin*? What are `COND1` and `COND2`? What is `input_flag`? What is even the point of optimizing if nearly all the time is spent in `Do****Thing`? If I got this on an exam, I would tear it up.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I posted the whole text and code that was at this task... I also found it a bit wierd before I posted it here... I can't answer you the questions about `b`, `COND1` or `input_flag`, since I don't have any more data than what you can see above...

Comment: @jakamojster: Who posted this nonsense for you? They need some flaming.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey My professor and assistant. But I would rather not give any names...

Comment: @jakamojster: Then pass along the comments to them. I was a professor. How anyone could give this to students is a mystery to me.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I will do that and even ask him some additional questions about this. But can you perhaps post an answer as efficient as it is possible from current data, so some other users can use it in the future as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although most of these optimizations will be performed by an optimizing compiler for your automatically, it's still good to understand what the compiler is doing behind your back.
Here are a few possibilities:

1. **Constant folding**

   The division of 3.14 by 180 involves two compile-time constants, so it can be computed in advance and only the result stored in the binary. This saves us computations at runtime, which speeds up the execution of the code.

   ```
   3.14/180 = 0.0174444   // assume 64-bit precision, like a double
   ```

   Thus, the code becomes:

   ```
   for(i=0;i<10000;i++) {    
     if ( (t1==0) && (t2==0) && (t3==0) ) 
        a = sin(45*b*0.0174444);  
     else  
        a = sin(135*b*0.0174444);  

     if ( condition2 & COND1 ) 
        DoOneThing(a);
     else if ( condition2 & COND2 ) 
        DoAnotherThing(a); 
     else 
        DoYetAnotherThing(a); 
   }
   ```
2. **Common subexpression elimination**

   Notice that, in the assignment to `a`, both sides of the `if` statement contain the same calculation. Whatever is the same regardless of the evaluation of the conditional can be hoisted out and done unconditionally. Thus:

   ```
   if ( (t1==0) && (t2==0) && (t3==0) ) 
      a = sin(45*b*0.0174444);  
   else  
      a = sin(135*b*0.0174444);
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   a = b*0.0174444;
   if ( (t1==0) && (t2==0) && (t3==0) ) 
      a *= 45;  
   else  
      a *= 135; 
   a = sin(a);
   ```

   This doesn't directly make the code execute more quickly, although it could conceivably reduce the *size* of the code (since the same thing won't be evaluated twice in two different places), and sometimes reductions in size can result in speed improvement (due to more optimal use of the cache, etc.).

   In fact, looking more carefully, we notice that `temp` is invariant across all iterations of the `for` loop, since `b` is not modified inside of the loop. This means it can be hoisted up even higher:

   ```
    a = b*0.0174444;
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++) {
       if ( (t1==0) && (t2==0) && (t3==0) ) 
          a *= 45;  
       else  
          a *= 135; 
       a = sin(a); 

      // etc.
    }
   ```

   This *will* result in a speed improvement, because now we don't need to compute `temp` 10000 times—we just compute it once, store it, and reuse it each time through the loop.
3. **Loop-invariant code promotion**

   We just got a taste of this optimization, but there's more that can be done. Looking at the `for` loop, you'll see that the only variable being modified is `i`. In the body of the loop, there are no expressions that depend on the value of `i`, which means that none of these results actually need to be computed inside of the loop. Thus, we can hoist them outside of the loop so that they are only done once, instead of repeated 10000 times.

   There is only one caveat: we don't know what the function calls (`DoOneThing`, `DoAnotherThing`, and `DoYetAnotherThing`) do internally, so we can't make any assumptions. (A compiler could, if the function's definitions were visible to it.) All we know is that they only depend on the value of `a`, so we just need to ensure that each function is called 10000 times.

   ```
     a = b*0.0174444;
     if ( (t1==0) && (t2==0) && (t3==0) ) 
         a *= 45;  
     else  
         a *= 135;
     a = sin(a);  

     if ( condition2 & COND1 )
         for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
             DoOneThing(a);
     else if ( condition2 & COND2 ) 
         for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
             DoAnotherThing(a);
     else 
         for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
             DoYetAnotherThing(a);
   ```

   This will be (significantly) faster because we don't have to test the `if` conditions each time through the loop, or do any of the other calculations.

There are certainly other optimizations possible, but these are the big ones that you are probably expected to see. As others have commented, this is pretty terrible code.

Comment: You exaplained it really well. Now finally it all makes sense together. Thank you Cody.